# Find the total number of possible permutations of all the letters of the word RESERVE.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am always confused on how to answer questions like this :

Find the total number of possible permutations of all the letters of the word RESERVE.

Find the number of these permutations in each of the following cases where:

i) E is the first letter.

ii) the two Rs come together.

iii) S and V come at the ends of the permutations.

Please explain how to do it and why is it done like that. Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused about condition (iii). Does each permutation have to end in SV, or can it end with VS, or something else?

Comment: (iii)... or...(re: "at the **ends** of"") meaning perhaps $S$ comes on the front end, and $V$ on the back end, or vice versa?

Comment: S at the front end and V at the back end, or vice versa

Comment: But then E couldn't be the first letter.

Comment: In (iii), I'm asking if you mean permutations like $SxxxxxV$ and or $VxxxxxS$, such that the sandwich the remaining $5$ letters? Separately, I think each scenario is a separate consideration (not that all of $i - iii$ be met simultaneously), @Henning.

Comment: "How to do it" for this kind of problem - usually do some of a) split letter placement into key zones, and b) aggregate collections of codependent letters, and c) identify secondary placement letters

Comment: @Joffan: I can usually work out that kind of counting problems, and yet I cannot understand your description at all...

Comment: @Jordan : You are right. The 3 parts are separate, the considerations are not to be met simultaneously. There's an answer for each part.

Answer (score 4):

There are $7!$ permutations of seven *distinct* letters., but in our case we have three occurrences of $E$ and two occurrences of $R$, so we need to divide by $2!3!$, as given any permutation we can rearrange the $E's$ in $3!$ different ways and rearrange the $R's$ in $2!$ different ways without changing the word. So the total number of permutations is $7!/3!2!=420$.

For (i), assume the first letter of the word is $E$. So we have a permutation of the form $E******$, where  $******$ is some permutation of $E,E,R,R,S,V$. Using the same idea as above, we can rearrange these in $6!/2!/2!=180$ different ways, so there are $180$ different permutations that begin with $E$.

For (ii), we treat $RR$ as a single letter (call it $P$) as we know that these two $R's$ must always be adjacent. So this is equivalent to the number of permutations of $PESEVE$, which is $6!/3!=120$ by the reasoning above.

For part (iii), we have two cases. In the first case the permutation is of the form $S*****V$ and in the other case it is of the form $V*****S$. So the question is: how many ways can we arrange $R,R,E,E,E$ in the middle? This is just the number of permutations of $R,R,E,E,E$, which is $5!/2!3!$. As we have two cases, we need to multiply this by $2$, so the final answer is $5!/3!=20$.